# handle data returned from an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following script to load an HTML page that is generated from a node.js server:

```
    (function nodeLoader(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://oclock.dyndns.org:8000",
            method: "get",
            data: {hk: hk },
            success: function(data){
                var visibile = $("div.scheda:visible").attr("id");
                $('.scheda').hide('fast',function(){$('#99').html(data).show();});
                setTimeout( function(){
                    //devo prendere id del messaggio visualizzato e settarlo a letto
                    $('.scheda').hide('fast',function(){$('#'+visibile).show().html(data);});
                },30000 );
            }
        });
    })();
```

the page loaded is the following:

```
<div id="container"></div>

<script>
// create a new websocket
var socket = io.connect('http://oclock.dyndns.org:8000');
// on message received we print all the data inside the #container div
socket.on('notification', function (data) {
    var msgs = '';
    $.each(data.flashmsgs,function(index,flashmsg){
        msgs += "<div>"
        msgs += "<h3>Messaggio inviato da " + flashmsg.created_by + "</h3><br>";
        msgs += "<p>" + flashmsg.testo + "</p></div>";
    });
    $('#container').html(msgs);
});
</script>
```

What I am trying to get is to add to nodeLoader a if (in success function) that says: if #container contains data (the node.js server is fetching something) then do hide and show. 
How can I do this? How to drill down data variable? The only idea I got is to change the node.js server to serve a json array instead of the page but I'd like not to rewrite the server by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and it's really very painful to find a flexible way of passing some metadata together with `HTML`. Of course, the best way is using `JSON`, but in case you cannot do such changes, there are still few possible solutions to accomplish this without rewriting a lot of code.

The first one is to include some metadata in a comment node, for example:

```
<!--META:{"count":3}-->
<ul>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 2</li>
    <li>Message 3</li>
</ul>
```

The second one is to pass `<script>` tag with some code while declaring some callback, e. g. `dataLoaded` before inserting the `HTML` into document. Keep in mind that this method is *potentially* unsafe:

```
<ul>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 2</li>
    <li>Message 3</li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">dataLoaded({"count":3})</script>
```

The third one is to manually manipulate data, however it is not a very good practice to make `JavaScript` code depend on `HTML` `DOM` structure very much.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data) {
        var count = $(data).find('li').length; // count == 3
    }
});
```

Finally, similar to the first way, you can just use some hidden nodes:

```
<input type="hidden" name="count" value="3" />
<ul>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 2</li>
    <li>Message 3</li>
</ul>
```

...or even use `data-*` attributes:

```
<ul class="messages" data-count="3"> <!-- NOTE: Don't forget to cast attribute value to Integer in JavaScript -->
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 2</li>
    <li>Message 3</li>
</ul>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes! So you say: load data in the target div, see if data-count>0 and then show the div?

Comment: @LelioFaieta yep, any way you wish :)